# After installing OpenCV, the qr code detector is missing: AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'QRCodeDetector'

Tags: python3

SOLVED by doing this in bash: pip3 install opencv-contrib-python

Thank you Kasonnara!

I am dabbling with qr codes in Python.

I installed like this:

sudo apt install opencv-python3

I am following the instructions [here](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/generate-read-qr-code-python).

When I get to: detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector() I get this error in the Python shell:

> > > > detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector() Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in 
> > > > detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector() AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'QRCodeDetector'

Can I add the detector somehow?

Are the Ubuntu binaries incomplete?

Should I uninstall then reinstall from source code??

In the Idle shell I get:

> > > > cv2 <module 'cv2' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>
> > > > len(dir(cv2)) 1704

The length is shorter than other users' reported length. Maybe some modules are missing??

Comment: Which version of opencv did you get? QR Code reader need version 4.0 or newer. I know that `pip3 install opencv-contrib-python` give a recent version. I don't now for the apt version. However I only found a *python3-opencv* package not *opencv-python3*.

Comment: How would I get the version? I suppose it is fairly recent, from the Ubuntu repositories, but maybe not the very latest version. I don't really need cutting-edge stuff. I tried pip3 install python3-opencv but this also fails: not found error.

Comment: pip doesn't have a package *python3-opencv*, that's the name of the apt package. There is many pip package that install opencv, personnaly I used *opencv-contrib-python*. Also to get the opencv version you can run import cv2 in a python interpreter, then print `cv2.version.opencv_version`

Comment: Also note that, when you don't find a package, the seach command is useful to find the exact name,  `apt search <some keyword>` or `pip3 search <some keyword>`.

Comment: Thank you very much! pip3 search opencv (I didn't know that) shows me many many packages!! How can I get them all?

Comment: pip3 install opencv-python fails with the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skbuild'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113054/discussion-between-pedroski-and-kasonnara).